# Define custom SSH key or find autogenerated SSH key in KOPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I'm using KOPs to launch a Kubernetes cluster in the AWS environment.

1. Is there a way to set a predefined SSH key when calling `create cluster`?
2. If KOPs autogenerates the SSH key when running `create cluster`, is there a way to download this key to access the cluster nodes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read the Kops [SSH docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/security.md#ssh-access):

> When using the default images, the SSH username will be admin, and the SSH private key is be the private key corresponding to the public key in kops get secrets --type sshpublickey admin. When creating a new cluster, the SSH public key can be specified with the --ssh-public-key option, and it defaults to ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.

So to answer your questions:

1. Yes, you can set the key using `--ssh-public-key`
2. When `--ssh-public-key` is not specified Kops does not autogenerate a key, but rather uses the key found in `~.ssh/id_rsa.pub`